# Why am I getting a 503 error when changing Route 53 to point to load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been trying to run my site on https and have done the following below.  Upon doing so, I've ran into a 503 error when navigating to my site.

1. I've configured the SSL certificate for port 443.
2. I've redirected port 80 to port 443
3. I've configured Route 53 to point to the load balancer for my domain name.

I believe there might be something off with my Load Balancer's security groups Inbound rules (screenshot attached) but I'm not entirely sure.

How can I get rid of this 503 error?

[image]

Comment: What about your VPC and subnets? ALB must be in public subnet Is it? Your question lacks details of your setup.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for a 503 error when using a load balancer is that there are no healthy instances registered with the load balancer. To check this, you can go to the load balancer in the AWS console and click on the Targets tab. Make sure that there is at least one healthy instance registered with the load balancer.

If there are healthy instances registered with the load balancer, then the next thing to check is the security groups. The security groups for the load balancer need to allow inbound traffic on port 443.

In the screenshot you attached, the security groups for the load balancer only allow inbound traffic on port 80. To fix this, you need to add a new inbound rule to the security groups that allows traffic on port 443.

To add a new inbound rule, follow these steps:

Go to the Security Groups page in the AWS console.
Select the security groups for the load balancer.
Click on the Edit button.
Click on the Add Rule button.
Select the TCP protocol.
Enter 443 in the Port Range field.
Enter 0.0.0.0/0 in the Source field.
Click on the Save button.

Additionally, You can try this

Make sure that the load balancer is in the same Availability Zone as the instances that you are registering with it.

Make sure that the load balancer is in the same VPC as the instances that you are registering with it.

Make sure that the health check for the load balancer is configured correctly.

Make sure that the scaling policy for the load balancer is configured correctly.